# Pointers pointing in Inherited classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, subclass, derived-class

Suppose we have a BaseClass Character and three SubClasses Good, Bad, Zombie.
Also assume we have two pointers

`Character* ptr1,ptr2;`

that point in class Good,Bad or Zombie. I want to create a part of code like this:

`if ((ptr1 "shows" Good)&&(ptr2 "shows" Bad)) {...}
else if ((ptr1 "shows" Good)&&(ptr2 "shows" Zombie)) {...}
else if ...`

and so on. How can I write such a statement? I have a hard time understanding virtual functions, polymorphism and inheritance but feel free to explain in terms of those too.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: You could use `dynamic_cast` to check if `ptr#` is convertible to either of the derived classes.

Comment: (`ptr2` is not declared as a pointer)

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a virtual public method in Character that returns an enum class representing the type of character, for example

```
virtual CharacterType GetCharacterType();
....
if((ptr1->GetCharacterType() == CharacterType::Good) && ptr2->GetCharacterType() == CharacterType::Bad)) {...}
```

or a virtual method that confirms the type of character.

```
virtual bool Is(CharacterType characterType);
....
if((ptr1->Is(CharacterType::Good) && ptr2->Is(CharacterType::Bad)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic_cast` in the following manner:

```
if (dynamic_cast<Good*>(ptr1) && dynamic_cast<Bad*>(ptr2)) {
  ...
} else if (dynamic_cast<Good*>(ptr1) && dynamic_cast<Zombie*>(ptr2)) {
  ...
} else if ...
```

Comment: dynamic_cast also throws std::bad_cast